# Helper or Library for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a project using CodeIgniter and I want to implement a function which will log actions in to the database. For example, when someone is making a post I want to log the IP Address, the action type, a note and if it was successful. The function is ready and everything should work fine. My problem is where should I place this function. Is it a helper a library or a model? Please note that I need to access the database.

The code for the log:

```
function add_to_log($entry_type, $entry_note, $entry_execution_owner)
{
    $data = array(
        'entry_type' => $entry_type,
        'entry_note' => $entry_note,
        'entry_execution_owner' => $entry_execution_owner
    );
    $this->db->insert('action_log', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Where is the best place to put it? (NOOB question: if it is placed as model is it possible to access it from the url?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you included in your question should be in a model, because it's a database interaction.

Personally, I might also write a logging library (or even extend CodeIgniter's log library) if you plan to have a variety of different logging methods. Otherwise, just using the model is fine.

(And for the NOOB question: not without writing a controller, no.)